# How many alternatives does a 14-bit ADC have

Tags: adc, alternatives

I am a bit confused what alternatives are or how to find out how many are in an ADC. The book I have wasn't much help and I need to find this out for a project. Does anyone know the answer or how to find out? thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "alternatives"? Are you talking about the \$2^{14}\$ output codes?

Comment: This question makes no clear sense.

Answer (score 8):

The answer has nothing at all to do with ADCs, but is simple binary.

The value given by the ADC is 14-bits wide, so therefore it has a possible \$2^{14}\$ combinations, or 16384.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I thought but for some reason I thought it made no sense...

Answer (score 3):

You take the number of bits (14 in this case) and then you take 2, double it, and then double that for a total doubling as many times as you have bits, like this:

```
     BITS       n
     -------------
      1         2
      2         4
      3         8 
      4        16
      5        32
      6        64
      7       128
      8       256
      9       512
      10     1024
      11     2048
      12     4096
      13     8192
      14    16384
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that while there are 16,384 combinations, reading the ADC returns 0 thru 16,383.

Comment: (1) The answer 16,384 was already provided 2 or 3 times in this thread.  (2) Single line is too thin for an answer on EE.SE